# Cannot send request from client side to server side in a MERN project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

While working on a personal project, everything was fine. But unfortunately I'm having a peculiar problem, as I cannot find out the reason behind this problem. Please let me describe the problem. Here the the backend point to which I'm trying to send requests from frontend.

```
router.get("/profile/:username", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.params.username })
        const posts = await Post.find({ userId: user._id })
        req.status(200).json(posts)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
})
```

This is my frontend point from where I'm trying to send requests

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      const res = username
        ? await axios.get("posts/profile/"+username)
        : await axios.get("posts/timeline/638b46766863c22bd1c7e242")
      setPosts(res.data)
    }
    fetchPosts()
  }, [username])
```

`username` is coming from another file where I wrote `<Feed username={"Shibly"}/>`. I want to have data from `localhost:3000/api/posts/profile/Shibly`, but I'm getting `404` error.

Here is the screenshot of network tab.
[image: screenshot]

Note that, `await axios.get("posts/timeline/638b46766863c22bd1c7e242")` is working properly.

Please someone help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi there. What is the base URL of the `router` in `router.get("/profile/:username", { ... })`? Is it possible that the endpoint is `/users/profile/:username`, while you're trying to access `/posts/profile/:username`?

Comment: @abemscac no brother, it's ```/posts/profile/:username```. But the problem is the route is getting changed somehow and I cannot find out that.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are hitting this API endpoint from the front end that I see from your network tab. Please check whether this API endpoint is exist or not on the backend side.

http://localhost:3000/profile/posts/profile/Shibly

Also, you can use this way for the dynamic route in frontend

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      const res = username
        ? await         axios.get(`posts/profile/:${username}`)
        : await axios.get("posts/timeline/638b46766863c22bd1c7e242")
      setPosts(res.data)
    }
    fetchPosts()
  }, [username])
```

Comment: I don't know why this route is getting changed. My ```proxy``` is ```http://localhost:5000/api``` and I'm trying to access from ```/posts/profile/username```, why or how the route is getting changed, I don't know.